# Sequelize order by for nested associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem including an order condition to a sequelize request. Here is the code for my request. Bascically I have a table called 'company_monetization' which includes an association to 'monetization' which includes an association to the table 'transaction'.

I want to order the request by an attribute from transaction called date. I have tried many implementations for the order condition but I always get the next error:

Unable to find a valid association for model, 'monetization'

Here is the code for my request:

```
exports.findAll = async (order) => {
  orderCondition = getOrder(order);
  const monetization = await models.company_monetization.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.imc,
        required:true,
        as: 'imc'
      },{
      model: models.company,
      required:true,
      as: 'company_origin',
      include: [{
        as: 'country',
        model: models.country,
        required:true
      }]
    },{
      model: models.company,
      required:true,
      as: 'company_final',
      include: [{
        as: 'country',
        model: models.country,
        required:true
      }]
    },{
      model: models.monetization,
      as:'id_monetization',
      required: true,
      include: [{
        model: models.transaction,
        as:'id_transaction',
        required: true,
        include: [{
          as: 'id_origin_coin_coin',
          model: models.coin,
          required: true
         },{
          as: 'id_final_coin_coin',
          model: models.coin,
          required: true
         }]
       }]
    }],
    raw: true,
    nest: true,
    order: [
      [
        models.monetization, {model: models.transaction, as: 'id_transaction'},
        'date', order
      ]
    ]
  });

  return monetization;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send the models in a array.

I have Coupon => Commerce => CommerceType models and I want to order by CommerceType.id

in the order I write this:

```
order: [
          ['CommerceId', 'CommerceTypeId', 'id', 'ASC']
       ]
```

Before in the models I have:

```
Coupon.belongsTo(Commerce, {
    foreignKey: 'commerceId',
    as: 'CommerceId'
});
```